# Overriding react-bootstrap CSS with custom SASS

Tags: webpack, sass, react-bootstrap

I am working to create a custom application using react and bootstrap with webpack and SASS. I have been able to hook everything up correctly (for the most part), except I am trying to override some of the default bootstrap styles inside of my react components but it does not seem to be working.

Here is my file structure

```
webpack.config.js
app/
--index.html
--main.scss
--renderer.js
--components/
----navigation/
------index.js
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const myConfig = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve('./app/renderer.js'),
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&path=http://localhost:5555/__webpack_hmr',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    ],

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    target: 'web',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap',
            },
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        plugins: [
                            'transform-class-properties',
                            'transform-decorators-legacy',
                            'transform-es2015-classes',
                            'react-hot-loader/babel'
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './app/static'),
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:5555/static/',
    },
}

module.exports = [ myConfig ]
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root'></div>
        <script src="http://localhost:5555/static/bundled.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

renderer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import './main.scss'

import Navigation from './components/navigation'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Navigation />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

navigation/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
    clickHandler = () => {
        console.log("Hello World")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar id="navigationRoot" inverse staticTop>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a onClick={this.clickHandler}>SiteName</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                </Navbar.Header>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

main.scss

```
.navbar-brand {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

In the main.scss I have tried to override the color of the bootstrap navbar-brand style as an example from the SASS file, however it appears that the [bootstrap.min.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css) file does not allow me to override the style. I know that the main.scss file is being included in the renderer build because I can add something like this to main.scss and the style is picked up in the webpage.

```
body {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Bundled file is [here](https://gist.github.com/didomenicom/b41fb7225cbc81c35d7607981268a426)

What am I missing that would cause the styles not to be overridden by the main.scss file?

Comment: what does your bundled.js look like? Where is your main.scss being compiled and included in your html? is it included through bundled.js?

Comment: I believe I see it on line 9546 of the [bundled file](https://gist.github.com/didomenicom/b41fb7225cbc81c35d7607981268a426#file-gistfile1-txt-L9546). The only include is in renderer.js. I have also added the webpack config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your webpack config options for `css-loader`.
You are using the option for `localIdentName` which is meant to generate local class names in order to avoid overwriting existing classes; however, your goal *is* to overwrite the existing bootstrap classes and localization of your classnames is hindering you: 
 <strike>`localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'`</strike>

**webpack.config.js (partial view)**:

```
        {
            test: /.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                        sourceMap: true,
                        importLoaders: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
```

Additionally, it appears that bootstrap will apply a css rule with higher specificity `.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand` than the one you have, so your css wouldn't be applied. If you use the same selector in your `main.scss`, then your style will take precedence and overwrite bootstrap's style:

**main.scss**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly this didn't work :( 

If I go with your example of creating an entry.scss file and including the content like you have in the alternative method, it still doesn't work. If I just comment out the first import line and have a .navbar-brand in the file, it still does not appear. Any thoughts on where I should be looking?

Comment: @mightymouse3062 Did it break during compiling or did the css rules not work as expected again?

Comment: @mightymouse3062 I changed my answer to a working solution. I had to run your code locally to tweak it to find the issue.

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to get it to work by also removing the css-loader "modules" option. I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: @miir I don't have the `localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'` But still it's not working.